# Locating discontinuities in functions

Tags: calculus, continuity

My professor does not bother to explain how to do it, but bothers to arrange a quiz... so here is my question
How to locate a point of didcontinuiity

Find all points of discontinuity:
$f(x) = (x^2-3)/(x^2+2x-8)$

I would really appreciate it if you could also explain how you came up with thr answer briefly, because i am finding the chapter **continuity** extremely difficult.

Comment: That function doesn't have discontinuities, although I know many would be tempted to say that it has discontinuities wherever $x^2 + 2x - 8 = 0$.

Comment: @Arthur: would you prefer to say the function's  domain is disconnected since it does not include $x=2$ or $x=-4$?

Comment: @Henry Yeah, domain is disconnected, the function isn't defined there, take your pick. Discontinuity is the wrong one, though.

Comment: @Arthur Are you simply stating the obvious that the function is continuous in the punctured plane $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{-4,2\}$

Comment: @MarkViola You'd be surprised how many people firmly believe that $1/x$ has a discontinuity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)$ has no points of discontinuity, but there are points on the real line $\Bbb R$ where $f$ is undefined.  But being undefined is not the same as being discontinuous.

---

Fun fact:  All [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) are continuous on their domains.

(Note that this excludes piecewise functions, but I don't think piecewise functions technically count as elementary functions anyway.. Not entirely sure on that.)

$f(x) = \dfrac{x^2-3}{x^2+2x-8}$ is an elementary function.

Therefore $f(x)$ is continuous on its domain, i.e., $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere it's defined.

$f(x)$ is defined everywhere except where $x^2 + 2x - 8 = 0$.

$x^2 + 2x - 8 = 0$ exactly when $x = 2$ or $x=-4$.

So $f(x)$ is defined on $(-\infty, -4) \cup (-4, 2) \cup (2, +\infty)$.

Therefore $f(x)$ is continuous on $(-\infty, -4) \cup (-4, 2) \cup (2,+\infty)$.

(Some people might say that last line is incorrect and will instead insist that we say "$f(x)$ is continuous on $(-\infty, -4)$, continuous on $(-4,2)$, and continuous on $(2, +\infty)$."  Just know what your instructor wants.)

It is **not** correct to say $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=-4$ and $x=2$.  It's incorrect to say that because $f(x)$ is not even defined there.  For a function to be discontinuous at a point, the function must be defined at that point.

Answer (score 4):

All polynomials are continuous in $\mathbb R$.

All rational fractions (ratios of polynomials) are continuous in their domain (the whole of $\mathbb R$, except the zeroes of the denominator).

This is because the sum, difference, product and quotient (except where $0$) of two continuous functions are continuous functions, and $x$ and constants are continuous functions.

Answer (score 4):

The answers given so far perhaps should be directed, not to the OP, but to OP's instructor or to the author of OP's textbook

It is a fact that most elementary calculus textbooks define "continuity at a point" in such a way that "point" means a point in $\mathbb{R}$. The standard definition in such standard texts is

The statement that the function $f$ is continuous at the point $a\in\mathbb{R}$ means that

1. $a$ lies in the domain of $f$
2. $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists
3. $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$

Given this definition of continuity at a point (of $\mathbb{R}$) the function

$$ f(x) = \dfrac{x^2-3}{(x+4)(x-2)} $$

clearly fails both the first and the second conditions of the definition at $a=-4$ and $a=2$.